# How to copy texture from context to another context inside GPU?

Tags: multithreading, directx, textures

for example,texA is created on deviceA in threadA, texB is created on deviceB in threadB,deviceA and deviceB use the same GPU, so how can I use ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource()(or CopySubresourceRegion()) to copy texA to texB inside GPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one of the textures so it can be shared across devices.

If you only support Win8 and newer, and both devices are D3D 11.1, the recommended way is specify `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_NTHANDLE` and `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_KEYEDMUTEX` flags, in `MiscFlags` field of `D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC`.

Once created, QueryInterface for IDXGIResource1 interface. Call `IDXGIResource1::CreateSharedHandle` on that interface. You don’t need name, pass `nullptr`. Specify `DXGI_SHARED_RESOURCE_READ` if you’ll copy from this texture into another device, or `DXGI_SHARED_RESOURCE_WRITE` if you’ll copy stuff from another device into this texture.

You’ll get a HANDLE value. Then, on second device, call `ID3D11Device1::OpenSharedResource1`, passing that handle. If succeeded, you’ll get `ID3D11Texture2D` pointer of that texture, shared into the second D3D device. Then you can call `CopyResource` or any oother D3D API on the second device, to copy data between textures. Don’t forget to `CloseHandle` once you’ve opened that texture on second device.

If you have D3D 11.0 or still supporting Windows 7, the workflow is slightly different. Use `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED` resource flag when creating a resource, call `IDXGIResource::GetSharedHandle` to obtain the handle, call `ID3D11Device::OpenSharedResource` to open that texture on another device, and do not call `CloseHandle` on that handle.